# Устраните ошибку при компиляции кода

Tags: python

```
thimbles = [input() for i in range(int(input()))]
thimbles_temp = []
order = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    for j in range(int(input()):
        order.append(int(input()) - 1)
    for index in order:
        thimbles_temp.append(thimbles[index])
    thimbles = thimbles_temp
print(*thimbles, sep="\n")
```

выдает ошибку(см. ниже) , я думал может со скобочками не так что-то, но все в порядке и не понимаю из за чего такая ошибка?

> stdout: /bin/sh ./build.sh 1>&2 Makefile:2: recipe for target 'build'
>
> failed
>
> stderr: ./solution.py:1:1: E902 TokenError: EOF in multi-line
>
> statement Код не соответствует стандарту PEP8 или в нем есть
>
> синтаксические ошибки make: *** [build] Error 1

Comment: за что минусуют?что не так?

Comment: Вместо изображения лучше вставить текст, чтобы он находился через поиск.

Comment: Минусуют, потому что вопрос вызван опечаткой и он не имеет ценности для сообщества. Такие вопросы лучше всего закрывать и удалять. Но теперь уже поздно, зачем-то дан и принят ответ.

Comment: @mkkik и что? у каждого бывает такое.у вас опечаток не было? я вот не вижу и все в упор какую то опечатку, тем более когда указывало на 1 строку зачем то, когда там было все верно, я не видел в упор что в какой то следующей строке не хватало скобочки при том что указывало на 1 строку, поэтому я подумал ошибка где то в синтаксисе и глупо так понижать из за этого

Comment: @МихаилМуругов сейчас исправлю

Comment: Опечатки бывают у всех, но пользы вопросу это не прибавляет. Адекватный сценарий в таких случаях: вопрос - комментарий с указанием на опечатку - удаление автором. P.S. в борьбе с опечатками есть отличные помощники - IDE.

Comment: @mkkik согласен, но скажите тогда это еще тем , кто минусовал , чтоб в следующий раз если такое будет, то чтоб они поступали по такой схеме

Comment: Ничего не понял, что и кому я должен сказать, и почему вас возмущают минусы на бесполезном вопросе. Не надо воспринимать минусы как личное оскорбление. Я поставил минус, потому что считаю, что такие вопросы должны удаляться. Возможно, остальные минусующие имеют схожее мнение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

закрывающую скобку забыли:

```
for j in range(int(input()):
```

а вообще загоните свой код сюда:
http://pep8online.com/

и посмотрите что еще выдаст по всяким отступам и т.д.

Comment: да,действительно забыл скобку, а почему тогда указывало на первую строку?

Comment: возможно из-за скобки просто компилятор с ума сошел и думал, что это все еще одна строка - кто ж их поймет - PyCharm показывает конкретную строчку к примеру

Comment: спасибо, понял, а за что вопрос минусуют?что не так?

Comment: а кто ж из знает

Comment: просто я не понимаю, приложил код, все четко описал, объяснил проблему, прикрепил ошибку и минусуют